# Multiple google charts on one page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get several charts on one page  but only 1 chart can be rendered.

Few weeks ago it was fine, but now only works using setTimeout function on chart2.draw

Here's my code

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
  data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

  data.addRows([
    [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
    [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],

  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
      subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
  var chart2 = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material2'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  chart2.draw(data, options);
}
```

Any help?

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>code above...</script>
  <div id="linechart_material"></div>
  <div id="linechart_material2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please add HTML

Comment: When the other charts do not render, is there any error message?

Comment: just blank console((